# apache 2.4 - double encode already encoded query string in URL

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I need help regarding a requirement. We have Apache 2.4.6 installed

I have a URL which has an encoded query string:

```
https://example.com/home?testStr%3Dhello%26id%3Drad
```

I am trying to find out how to double encode only the query string part of the URL using mod_rewrite in Apache webserver to:

```
https://example.com/home?testStr%253Dhello%2526id%253Drad
```

This is for one of the issues I am trying to fix.

Comment: Just to confirm, you would like to have the query string to be double encoded?

Comment: might I ask WHY you are trying to do this? Why use encoded strings at all, that's a really ugly URL.

Comment: @Broco I cannot avoid this.. this request is sent by 3rd party and we get the request and validate and forward the request.. but there is a bug one of the product and we cannot apply patch as of now.. Our alternative is to double encode the query string...

Comment: @pacey - yes i need to double encode only query string part.. not the request URL....

Comment: I'm sorry but I still have issues comprehending. You have a web application, which requires the urls to be urlencoded (but only once), you have a third party accessing this application - with query strings urlencoded twice? Or is it the other way around: third party sends the query string urlencoded once and your application expects double-urlencoded query strings?

Comment: @pacey  3rd party -> validation -> web application...

Comment: @pacey 3rd party -> validation -> web application...  This is the order..      3rd party calls the web application . I intercept the request and validate , but there is a bug in one of products, so I have to double encode the query string before i validate so that the validation will decode the quersy string only once and forward to web application

Answer (score 2):

Just to echo the concerns in comments... this is a strange requirement. However, you can do this using mod_rewrite. For example, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(testStr%3Dhello%26id%3Drad)$
RewriteRule ^/?(home)$ /$1?%1 [B,NE,R,L]
```

This issues a temporary (302) redirect from `/home?testStr%3Dhello%26id%3Drad` to `/home?testStr%253Dhello%2526id%253Drad` (doubly encoded).

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded, so you match against the literal query string as given in the `RewriteCond` directive.

The `$1` backreference refers to the captured subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* ie. `home`.

The `%1` backreference refers to the captured subpattern in the last matched *CondPattern* (the `RewriteCond` directive) ie. the %-encoded query string (`testStr%3Dhello%26id%3Drad`).

The `B` (escape backreferences) flag on the `RewriteRule` directive %-encodes the backreference (`%1`) to effectively doubly-encode the query string.

The `NE` (noescape) flag prevents the *susbstitution* being further (triple) URL-encoded!

Comment: How did you get on with this?

Comment: Hi Sorry.. this didn't work.. the regex was not picked up by webserver..

Comment: What was the exact URL being requested? Maybe there were other differences on your system? (Proxy server etc.?) Any other directives in your config? (The order of directives can be important.) If the "regex was not picked up" then it's trivial to debug the request that the webserver sees, to find out why it didn't match. Incidentally, this was tested locally on Apache 2.4.7, using the exact URL as given in the question and it worked as intended.